# Base64 encoded output is different in Java/shell

Tags: java, shell, base64

I have been facing a issue in base64 encoding.

I had encoded a string "test" using Java base64 encoding.

My output is "dGVzdA0K".

When using the same string in Linux base64, I received "dGVzdAo=".

Why is there a difference? I have to pass my shell encoded output to Java base64 decoder.

When decoding both string in online decoders, it returns the expected string, but it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encoded strings differ in that the java former includes 2 newline characters `'\n'` at the end while the latter only has one.

You can tell by typing e.g. `echo dGVzdAo= | base64 --decode | od -c`

Comment: To fix this OP needs to use: `echo -n "test" | base64`